# Descargar archivos XLSX con Fast-Excel-Writer (Error con temporales)

Tags: php

estoy queriendo descargar archivos XLSX con Fast-Excel-Writer, funciona perfecto en el servidor con el siguiente código:

```
use \avadim\FastExcelWriter\Excel;

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT ....);

$data = [];
while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {

  $data[] = array(
      $rows['LASTNAME'],
      $rows['FIRSTNAME'],
      $rows['MIDNAME'],
      $rows['READERDESC'],
      $rows['EVENT_TIME_UTC']->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
      $rows['READERDESC_OUT'],
      $rows['EVENTS_OUT_TIME']->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
      $rows['CARDNUM'],
      $rows['SSNO'],
      $rows['FLDCONTRATO'],
      $rows['HORAS_TRABAJADAS']
    );
}

$excel = Excel::create(['Sheet1']);
$sheet = $excel->getSheet();

// Write heads
$sheet->writeRow(['APELLIDO', 'NOMBRE', 'SEGUNDO NOMBRE', 'LECTORA ENTRADA', 'HORA ENTRADA', 
'LECTORA SALIDA', 'HORA SALIDA', 'N TARJETA', 'LEGAJO / DNI', 'N CONTRATO', 'HORAS 
TRABAJADAS']);

// Write data
foreach($data as $rowData) {
   $rowOptions = [
       'width' => 60,
     ];
   $sheet->writeRow($rowData, $rowOptions);
}

$Descarga = "simple.xlsx";
$excel->save($Descarga);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$Descarga. "\"");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($Descarga);

unlink($Descarga);

exit();
```

Desde el Servidor funciona perfecto, crea los temporales en la carpeta Windows/Temp que esta por defecto ahí, y luego los elimina al realizar la descarga del archivo xlsx. El problema que tengo, es que desde el cliente, me tira el siguiente error:

> ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TEST\Reportes_MDZ\Web\vendor_old\avadim\fast-excel-writer\src\FastExcelWriter\Writer.php on line 265

Se que es un tema de permisos, ya que no todos acceden al servidor en el cual esta, mi pregunta es: Si se le puede decir al código que cree los temporales desde donde lo están solicitando, y luego los elimine, como hace en el servidor?

No encontré la forma de hacerlo, probé agregando esto, pero no hace nada:

```
$temporales= sys_get_temp_dir();
$excel = Excel::create(['Sheet1']);
$excel->setTempDir($temporales);
```

Si alguien sabe del tema o como poder realizarlo, os agradeceré!

Comment: Hola Matias, te recomiendo leer [Set Directory For Temporary Files](https://github.com/aVadim483/fast-excel-writer/blob/master/docs/01-workbook.md#set-directory-for-temporary-files) en la documentación. También deberías considerar utilizar el método [download](https://github.com/aVadim483/fast-excel-writer#simple-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Corrección de permisos:***

Puedes implementar algo como (si no tienes acceso a la terminal):

```
$nombreCarpetaTemporal = '/ruta/a/la/carpeta/temporal';

if (!is_dir($nombreCarpetaTemporal)) {
    mkdir($nombreCarpetaTemporal, 0777, true); // Crea la carpeta con permisos de escritura
}
```

Si tienes acceso a la terminal:

```
mkdir nombreCarpetaTemporal
chmod 0777 nombreCarpetaTemporal
```

Si tienes acceso `sudo`:

```
sudo mkdir nombreCarpetaTemporal
sudo chmod 0777 nombreCarpetaTemporal
```

***Implementación:***

```
\avadim\FastExcelWriter\Excel::setTempDir($nombreCarpetaTemporal);
$excel = \avadim\FastExcelWriter\Excel::create();
// Agregar contenido al archivo Excel
$excel->save('nombre_archivo.xlsx');
```

de esta manera estableces el temporal que vas a usar con `FastExcelWriter`

Comment: Me sigue pasando lo mismo, en el servidor funciona, crea la carpeta y agrega los temporales ahi, y descargar el archivo, pero desde el cliente, me dice: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied ... avadim\fast-excel-writer\src\FastExcelWriter\Writer.php on line 265

Comment: Sigue siendo problema con los permisos no con el codigo

Comment: fijate si el archivo Writer.php tiene permisos de ejecucion: 777 o ponselos desde el administrador de archivos.

Comment: Excelente! ya pude. Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Era tema de permisos en la ubicacion donde esta el archivo Writer.php

Answer (score 0):

LITERALMENTE EL MANUAL DICE:
Also, you can download generated file to client (send to browser)

```
$excel->download('download.xlsx');
```

usa esa linea para generar el archivo al navegador

REFERENCIA: https://github.com/aVadim483/fast-excel-writer

Comment: Si he leído el manual, pero cuando ponga con download me aparece esto: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method avadim\FastExcelWriter\Excel::download()